# experimental probability

Tags: probability

A coin is flipped 80 times. It lands on tails 47 times. Based on this data, what is the experimental probability that the coin will land on heads?

Comment: $1/2{}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: When you say coin, you mean a coin that has probability $p$ to land on heads and $1-p$ to land on tails, where $p \in (0,1)$, yes (otherwise it is, as others have noted, 1/2)? And when you say 'help me', you mean, 'Could anyone help me see, please? I've tried the following: ...' I assume that you explained your reasoning but that it magically got erased...

Comment: Do you mean "it lands tails *exactly* 47 times" (and not "*at least* 47 times")?  Do you mean "the coin will land on heads *on the next coin flip*"?

Comment: @snarski there is no reason to asume that the coin is unbiased and the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I see 33/80 is one answer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I think there is no reason to assume that Cephus wants to say *at least 47 times* or *at most 47 times* when he writes "47 times". *experimental probability* has a precise meaning (in wikipedia) as Barry Cipra told us, for the next and all other tosses of the coin. Maybe one can argue that a coin may land on its edge.

Comment: @miracle173 I'm not sure how this differs from what I wrote, care to elaborate?

Comment: @snarski maybe I misinterpreted parts of your post.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_probability), *experimental probability* is the relative frequency of an occurrence in an actual experiment, so I'd say the answer here (for the coin to land heads) is $33/80$.